# Deriving instances depending on a specific part of a data

Tags: haskell

I have the following code

```
type Position = (Int,Int)

data CheckError where
    LError :: Position -> LexerError  -> CheckError
    PError :: Position -> ParseError  -> CheckError
    SError :: Position -> StaticError -> CheckError
```

I need it to instance `Ord` but just by comparing the `Position` field in each constructor.

I got it to work with this:

```
data CheckError where
    LError :: Position -> LexerError  -> CheckError
    PError :: Position -> ParseError  -> CheckError
    SError :: Position -> StaticError -> CheckError
    deriving (Show)

instance Eq CheckError where
    (LError l _) == (LError r _) = l == r
    (LError l _) == (PError r _) = l == r
    (LError l _) == (SError r _) = l == r
    (PError l _) == (LError r _) = l == r
    (PError l _) == (PError r _) = l == r
    (PError l _) == (SError r _) = l == r
    (SError l _) == (LError r _) = l == r
    (SError l _) == (PError r _) = l == r
    (SError l _) == (SError r _) = l == r

instance Ord CheckError where
    compare (LError l _) (LError r _) = l `compare` r
    compare (LError l _) (PError r _) = l `compare` r
    compare (LError l _) (SError r _) = l `compare` r
    compare (PError l _) (LError r _) = l `compare` r
    compare (PError l _) (PError r _) = l `compare` r
    compare (PError l _) (SError r _) = l `compare` r
    compare (SError l _) (LError r _) = l `compare` r
    compare (SError l _) (PError r _) = l `compare` r
    compare (SError l _) (SError r _) = l `compare` r
```

But I find this code to be too repetitive. Is there any way to tell Haskell to compare directly with the `Position` field?

Comment: By the way, why do you use the GADT syntax for a monomorphic type?

Comment: @Yuuri I just did. When is it supposed to be used?

Comment: AFAIK, GADTs are used when constructors of a polymorphic ADT must return differently instantiated values, e.g.: `data CheckError a where GeneralError :: Position -> a -> CheckError a; SpecialError :: SpecialInfo -> CheckError SpecialInfo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd propose a slightly cleaner version with `on` combinator from `Data.Function`:

```
import Data.Function

instance Eq CheckError where
    (==) = (==) `on` pos

instance Ord CheckError where
    compare = compare `on` pos
```

where `pos` is defined as either a simple function or a record field (as it was suggested by @Xavier). This can be literally read as "comparation of `CheckError`'s is comparation on their positions".

Comment: Very elegant indeed! I didn't know about `on`.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps this way?

```
 instance Eq CheckError where
    a == b = pos a == pos b 
              where 
                pos (LError p _) = p
                pos (PError p _) = p
                pos (SError p _) = p
```

Comment: As it turns out, you can also use record syntax with GADTs. So `pos` could be defined for free.

Comment: That is, you can define `data CheckError where LError :: { pos :: Position, lerr :: LexerError } -> CheckError; PError :: { pos :: Position, perr :: ParseError } -> CheckError; SError :: { pos :: Position, serr :: StaticError } -> CheckError`

Comment: +1 When it seems like you "have" to write this kind of repetitive code in Haskell, the cause is almost always that you're really doing multiple things at once. Very often just factoring the concerns out into separate ideas (in this case "get the Position out of a CheckError" and "compare Positions") makes the boilerplate vanish.

Comment: Over here is it also possible to do `instance Eq CheckError where (_ a _) == (_ b _) = a == b` ? Not sure. When I try to load the program into GHCI I get some sort of GADT error so am unable to check it ...

Comment: @ssm you can't, it needs to specify a constructor

Comment: @ssm Also, to use GADTs (within GHC) be sure to add the following to the beginning of the file in order to make them available (since GADTs are an extension): `{-#LANGUAGE GADTs #-}`.

Comment: @XavierPinho: Thanks. This seems like something I hadn't used before and looks like something I should start using more often!